# Flutter with Firebase Firestore don't show the right icon (Like Button System)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm Trying to paint an like icon button, but i suspect that the build is not re-rendering after the new call to initstate:

Firebase Structure

[image: Firebase Structure]

Console Output

[image: Console Output]

Here is my code:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    likesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('likes').doc(currentUser);
    likesRef.get().then((value) {
      data = value.data();
      setState(() {});
    });
    postRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Products');
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('data $data');
   ...
                                          ...children: [
                                                  data != null &&
                                                          data.containsKey(
                                                              snapshot.data
                                                                      .docs[
                                                                  index]['uid'])
                                                      ? new IconButton(
                                                          icon: Icon(
                                                            EvaIcons.heart,
                                                          ),
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            _isLikedFunc();
                                                          },
                                                        )
                                                      : new IconButton(
                                                          icon: Icon(
                                                            EvaIcons
                                                                .heartOutline,
                                                          ),
                                                          onPressed: () {},
                                                        )...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code was ok, it was a database blank space on some fields,
thank you for watching